# RxJs return Observable if variable not undefined

Tags: angular, rxjs5

I would like to create a method getSelectedUser that return an Observable only if a private field is there (not undefined).

```
private user : User

init() {
   // user = loadingUser...
}

getSelectedUser(): Observable<User> {
    // return ???
}
```

The goal is that other component can subscribe this observable and receive the user once it is loaded.

Does someone have an idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then define user to be an observable:

```
private user: Subject<User> = new ReplaySubject<User>(1); // ensure that new registered component gets the last loaded user.

getSelectedUser(): Observable<User> {
   return user.asObservable();
}
```

then update the user when it is ready:

```
private someUserLoadingFunction(){
   ... retrieve user logic -> currentUser...
   this.user.next(currentUser);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer. It seems to work. But now, my component should wait the value is there before rendering. Do you know how I can do that?

Comment: I am missing info, but you can make it visible with `*ngIf="user | async"`

Comment: Just an additional question : If I subscribe this subject in a component, I will get memory leak as the component goes because I'm still subscribed to the subject. How Can I avoid that?

Comment: hold a subscription variable: `let subscription = someObservable$.subscribe(...)` and then in your `ngOnDestroy` call `subscription.unsubscribe()`

Comment: I've just found this solution. Thanks a lot for your help today @Meir.